# Do I need a diamond relationship to make this problem work?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I've trawled the internet trying to find an answer for this - I should preface this question with my being a total amateur.

EDIT: The Database type is mySQL
EDIT: The band sizes aren't dynamic; they're for showbands ie a 5 piece will always be Vocals | Guitar | Keys | Bass | Drums
EDIT: I've included some sample data at the bottom

So, the problem is thus:

---

I have a table of musicians (musiciansID)
I have a table roles (rolesID), which is their role in a band (vocals, guitar etc)

I have a table of musicians_roles (musiciansID, rolesID). Musicians can play many instruments.

I have a table of specific bands (bandID) (8 piece, 6 piece) etc

I have a table of band_roles (bandID, rolesID). 
Each band has a specific format eg 3 piece | Vocals, Guitar, Drums

---

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to enforce something like the following:

BandID = 1 (3 piece, say)

BandID has RolesID = 1,2,3 (Vocals, Bass, Drums)

and this is the bit where I fall down

BandID has MusiciansID = 1,2,3 (John, Paul, Ringo), but I'd like the constraint to fail if I tried to put Ringo as the bass player for example.

---

I'm SO sorry if this is super simple and I just don't have the vocabulary to search for it. I have a feeling the answer may be something similar to the link below, but I can't get it to work.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34040/many-to-many-and-weak-entities

*Some sample data*

Musicians:

Joe Bloggs
Sarah Samsonite
Sam Stalactite 
Don Bike
Tracy Shiney

Roles:

Vocals
Trumpet
Saxophone
Guitar
Bass
Drums
Keyboards

Musicians_roles:

Joe Bloggs, Saxophone
Joe Bloggs, Drums
Sarah Samsonite, Vocals
Sam Stalactite, Drums
Don Bike, Guitar
Tracy Shiney, Bass

Band_Roles:

5 piece, Vocals
5 piece, Keyboards
5 piece, Guitar 
5 piece, Drums 
5 piece, Bass
6 piece, Vocals
6 piece, Keyboards
6 piece, Guitar 
6 piece, Drums 
6 piece, Bass
6 piece, Sax

Musicians in band:

5 piece, Vocals, Sarah Samsonite
5 piece, Keyboards, NULL
5 piece, Guitar, NULL 
5 piece, Drums, Sam Stalactite 
5 piece, Bass, NULL

Then, say for example I tried to put Sarah Shiney on guitar, it would fail.

---

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Many bands tend to have a dynamic number of members, changing all the time. I'd re-consider if the specific bands table (bandID) (8 piece, 6 piece) really is needed.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you add the Database type Tag  you are using in the project please

Comment: @jarlh thanks for that! I've put an edit in. It's for show bands of a specific format, so they'll always have the same instrument lineup (but different musicians)

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks! I've added some data at the bottom

Comment: @Sana'aAl-ahdal thanks! I've edited it - I'm using (trying to use) mySQL.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to restrict this on db level. The app must validate relationships like that. Db relationshop constraints are pretty simple.

Comment: @Rudie okay thanks - that's kind of reassuring because this is driving me mad. ha

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Role ROL exists.
--
role {ROL}
  PK {ROL}
```

```
-- Musician MUS exists.
--
musician {MUS}
      PK {MUS}
```

```
-- Musician MUS can play role ROL.
--
musician_role {MUS, ROL}
           PK {MUS, ROL}

FK1 {MUS} REFERENCES musician {MUS}
FK2 {ROL} REFERENCES role     {ROL}
```

```
-- Band BND exists.
--
band {BND}
  PK {BND}
```

```
-- Band BND has role ROL.
--
band_role {BND, ROL}
       PK {BND, ROL}

FK1 {BND} REFERENCES band {BND}
FK2 {ROL} REFERENCES role {ROL}
```

The constraints, as I understood them from the example:

- *Each musician can play in at most one band; for each band: more than one musician can play in that band.*
- *For each band and role: exactly one musician plays in that band in that role.*

```
-- Musician MUS plays in band BND in role ROL.
--
musician_band_role {MUS, BND, ROL}
                PK {MUS}
                AK {BND, ROL}

FK1 {MUS, ROL} REFERENCES musician_role {MUS, ROL}
FK2 {BND, ROL} REFERENCES band_role     {BND, ROL}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

Comment: Hi Damir, 

Thanks so much for your answer - really interesting. 

One of the constraints is different (my fault for not explaining!):

Many iterations of the same band can exist (ie different bookings on the same night/ musician sick etc)

The second constraint is correct. 

Perhaps I could have:

Booking BKI exists
PK {BKI}

band BND belongs to booking BKI
band_booking {BND, BKI}
       PK {BND, BKI}

FK1 {BND} REFERENCES band {BND}
FK2 {BKI} REFERENCES booking {BKI}

and then 

MUS_BKI_BND_ROL with overlapping FK's? Running out of characters! 

Thank you so much!